# Converting nested dictionary to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dictionary where `Time#` and `device#` uniquely identifies the row.

```
d= {"Time1": {"device1": {"param1": 100, "param2": 0.1}}, "Time2": {"device1": {"param3": 0.1, "param1": 0.9}}}
```

Expected data frame should be

```
Time   device   param1  param2  param3
Time1  device1   100     0.1     
Time2  device1   0.9             0.1
```

I tried below but it does not work as expected

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,'index').rename_axis(columns='Time').reset_index()
```

My_result:

```
   Time  index     device1
    0     Time1  {'param1': 100, 'param2': 0.1}
    1     Time2  {'param3': 0.1, 'param1': 0.9}
```

Comment: please add the output of your try to the question

Comment: read this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-list-of-nested-dictionary-into-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 2):

You can do `concat` on a dict comprehension:

```
(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v).T for v in d.values()],
          keys=d.keys())
    .rename_axis(index=['Time','Device'])
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    Time   Device  param1  param2  param3
0  Time1  device1   100.0     0.1     NaN
1  Time2  device1     0.9     NaN     0.1
```

Comment: It works but i see  FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

  df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v).T for v in d.values()], keys=d.keys()).rename_axis(index=['Time', 'Device']).reset_index()

Comment: Pass `sort=False` to concat.